# A doubt on plot of $E$ versus $r$ for a point charge

Tags: electrostatics

Given is the Graphical Variation of $E$ (Electric field) on $x$ axis due to a Point Charge. [image]

(Coordinate axes aren't labelled on the book, $ X, X' , Y', Y $ was written by me.)

In left the plot is for $+q$ and in right for $-q$.
The $E$ of $-q$ $= - \frac{kQ}{r^2} $

Now, my question is, if we take $Q=+1C$

And,

$r=3×10^{9/2}$,

The $E$ of $-q$ $= - \frac{9×10^9}{9×10^9} = -1 $

Similarly for $r$ $=-3×10^{9/2}, \frac{3}{√2}×10^{9/2}, -\frac{3}{√2}×10^{9/2}, $ $E=-1, -2, -2 $ respectively.

So, the graph should be,

[image]

So, no line should be in $+y$ axis. But on the contrary the book says $E<0$ and the graph is in the second quadrant.

Why?

Also, the book says in the above diagram (Right side) that as $x→0 , E→∞$ but from my plot it is clear that as $x→0, E→-∞$ ($x$ and $r$ are the same thing.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> $x$ and $r$ are the same thing.

Your confusion arises because they are not the same thing.

---

If the electric field is written in terms of radial components then there is no complication.

$\vec E = E_{\rm r} \hat r = \dfrac{kQ}{r^2}\hat r$ and $\vec r = r \hat r$

The direction of $\vec E$ relative to $\hat r$ is completely determined by the sign of the charge $Q$.

The graph that you have attempted to draw at the end of your question could be a graph of the component of the electric field in the $\hat r$ direction against distance from the charge $r$ but should not show negative values of $r$.

---

The complication that you have highlighted arises because the book uses $\hat x$ as the unit vector.
The displacement from the origin is then $\vec x = x \hat x$ and $x$, the component of $\vec x$ in the $\hat x$ direction,  can be either positive or negative but because of the $x^2$ term the direction information seems to be lost.

$\vec E = E_{\rm x} \hat x$ where $E_{\rm x}$ is the component of the electric field in the $\hat x$ direction.

If one writes the electric field as $\vec E = E_{\rm x} \hat x=  \dfrac{kQ}{|x^3|}x\hat x$ then $\dfrac{kQ}{|x^3|}x$ is the component of the electric field in the $\hat x$ direction.

If you use this equation then the signs take care of themselves and you get the correct sign for the component of the electric field in the $\hat x$ direction as the sign of that component is determined by the sign of the product $Qx$.

$Q$ positive and $x$ positive $\Rightarrow$ electric field direction is $+\hat i$
$Q$ positive and $x$ negative$\Rightarrow$ electric field direction is $-\hat i$
$Q$ negative and $x$ positive $\Rightarrow$ electric field direction is $-\hat i$
$Q$ negative and $x$ negative $\Rightarrow$ electric field direction is $+\hat i$

as per the diagrams from your textbook.

Comment: I think the radial vector $r$ must always be positive. As per your (right) answer. Can you confirm me?

Comment: @RaviPrakash That is correct.

Answer (score 2):

Electric field is a vector, meaning it has both a magnitude and a direction. Since we're restricting ourselves to one dimension here, the electric field can point either in the $+x$ direction or in the $-x$ direction. In these plots, they have chosen the following convention as a shorthand for specifying direction: a positive value of $E$ corresponds to when $\vec{E}$ is pointing in the $+x$ direction, and a negative value of $E$ corresponds to when $\vec{E}$ is pointing in the $-x$ direction.

In the case of a positive charge at $x=0$, $\vec{E}$ will always point away from the charge. This means that $\vec{E}$ will point to the right for $x>0$, and it will point to the left for $x<0$. Using our convention above, this means that $E$ is positive for $x>0$ and negative for $x<0$.

In the case of a negative charge at $x=0$, $\vec{E}$ will always point toward the charge. This means that $\vec{E}$ will point left for $x>0$ and right for $x<0$. Using our convention above, this means that $E$ is negative for $x>0$ and positive for $x<0$.